# Buildfire Connection with Zapier to add new registrations to mailing list Issues

Tags: zapier, github-third-party-apps

We are using Zapier to have new registrations (signups) to our app be added to our mailing list platform (activecampaign).  It has been working for the last couple of months but all of a sudden it has stopped with no idication to why it is not working (no notificaation warning from Zapier).  Zapier can not help due to no backend access to buildfire and they see no issue on their side, therefore it's builfire.

Is there a way we can check the backend of the Buildfire platform to see what the issue could be?

Have tired recreating a Zap but now when I do I get an error message "failed to fetch an user search from BuildFire; Error while retrieving: JSON results array could not be located."

I have reached out to Buildfire support that directed us to come onto this platform.